# How can I rank images by only comparing them to each other?

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a large collection of images which I'm trying to sort according to quality by crowd-sourcing. Images can be assigned 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 stars according to how much the user likes them. A 5-star image would be very visually appealing, a 1-star image might be blurry and out of focus.

At first I created a page showing an image with the option to rate it directly by choosing 1-5 stars. But it was too time-consuming to to do this. I'd like to try to create an interface where the user is presented with 2 images side by side and asked to click the image s/he likes more. Using this comparison data of one image compared to another, is there then some way to convert it over to a score of 1-5?

What kind of algorithm would allow me to globally rank images by comparing them only to each other, and how could I implement it in python?

Comment: Don't you think, this is toooooooo broad to answer?

Comment: I'm looking for any specific algorithms that might do this. Not sure how to make it more specific

Comment: @ensnare for starters, you haven't specified what ranking means, why an image is better than another image and how an algorithm would be able to determine that.

Comment: @SimeonVisser ah ok, updated to be more specific

Comment: While I agree with the general sentiment that this is a bit broad, I think it's reasonable to read this as "how can I infer the [total order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) of a set given samples of the order between pairs of them". Since the ordering here is very subjective ("quality" means different things to different people), you'll most certainly run into the [triangle inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality), where a>b>c>a. If you *do* have triangle inequalities, you can't deduce a total ordering from your sample data

Comment: did you create such a webapp to rank picture, I`m thinking to do something like that to choose picture from google album

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like you need a ranking algorithm similar to what is used in sport to rank players. Think of the comparison of two images as a match and the one the user selects as the better one is the winner of the match. After some time, many players have played many matches and sometimes against the same person. They win some they lose some eh? How do you rank which is the best overall?

You can look at the [Elo Rating System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system). which is used in chess to rank chess players. There is an algorithm specified so it should be a matter of implementing in your language of choice.

Comment: this is very helpful, thank you. do you happen to know any resources for sample code in python?

Comment: @ensnare Quick rule of thumb - if you want a language X implementation of algorithm Y, Google for `X Y`. Applying this rule to `python Elo Rating System` gets some promising looking hits.

Answer (score 1):

Let each image start with a ranking of 3 (the mean of 1 … 5), then for each comparison (which wasn't equal) lower the rank of the loser image and increase the rank of the winner image.  I propose to simply *count* the +1s and the -1s, so that you have a number of wins and a number of losses for each image.

Then the value 1 … 5 could be calculated as:

```
import math

def rank(wins, losses):
  return 3 + 4 * math.atan(wins - losses) / math.pi
```

This will rank images higher and higher with each win, but it will lead to the silly situation that (+1010 / -1000) will be ranked alike with (+10 / -0) which is not desirable.

One can remedy this flaw by using a mean of the values:

```
def rank(wins, losses):
  return (3 + 4 * math.atan((wins - losses) / (wins + losses) * 10) / math.pi
          if wins + losses > 0 else 3)
```

Both curves will never *quite* reach 1 or 5, but they will come ever closer if an image always wins or always loses.

Comment: I like your function to add a curve to it - otherwise it very quickly gets to 5 or 0.

Comment: This is a good start, but it misses 99% of the data, which is in the knowledge that the ratings relation is (nearly) transitive. Also,  a image will have better quality if it has a win against a high quality image than a low quality image.

Comment: @goncalopp yes, that ELO principle takes this into account and my approach doesn't.  However, ELO is built for a situation in which comparisons are costly and rare.  *And* typically just two more-or-less equally ranked players are compared.  This both needs not be the case here; the OP can present randomly chosen images for comparison (without annoying chess players by an unfit and boring game).

Comment: @Alfe Thanks. Just to be clear the images can be chosen according to their current rankings, if that would yield better results. When I said randomly chosen I meant the starting case.

Comment: No, for my approach that would _not_ yield better results ;-)  But for chess players that's the only option (in order to not annoy the players), so the ranking system must be more complex.  For images, this does not seem necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to deal with a complex statistical model like the Elo rating system suggested by @VincentRamdhanie (which will yield optimal results), you can always model this as a simple [optimization problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimization_%28mathematics%29).

You have datapoints of the type `a>b`. If you assign values to a and b, `a>b` is simply a condition that evaluates to true or false. Then, one possible "solution" to this problem is to maximize the number of conditions (datapoints) that evaluate to true.

Since you already know your metric, all that is left is to choose a search algorithm. [Hill climbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing) is a very simple one. It works like this:

- assign to each rating a random value - this is your current solution
- change the value of one of the ratings
- if by performing the change, our metric (number of valid conditions) is improved, the change is incorporated in our current solution
- repeat until you're happy (typically, until you can't improve the solution for some time)

It's important to mention that this method will yield meaningful order between the images, but the ratings themselves will not have any meaning. There's no difference between a rating of 3 or 4 if there are no images with ratings between 3 or 4. After the search algorithm runs, you may want to simply take the order information, and distribute the images evenly in the rating space (if you have 3 images, they'll have final ratings of 1, 3 and 5, for example).

Here's some code to illustrate this:

```
import random

N_ELEMS= 5 #number of images
N_RATINGS= 5 #number of (faked) user-given ratings
MIN_SCORE, MAX_SCORE= 0.0, 5.0
N_ITERATIONS= 1000 #for search stopping condition

def random_score():
    #generate random score between MIN_SCORE and MAX_SCORE
    return MIN_SCORE+random.random()*(MAX_SCORE-MIN_SCORE)

elements=range(N_ELEMS) #this would be strings or objects in the real world
ratings= [] #tuples of (elem_a, elem_b), representing rating a<b
for i in range(N_RATINGS):
    #generate fake ratings
    while True:
        elem_a, elem_b=(random.choice(elements),random.choice(elements))
        if elem_a!=elem_b:
            break
    ratings.append((elem_a, elem_b))
scores= [random_score() for i in range(N_ELEMS)] #assign random scores

def evaluate_condition( rating ):
    #is a user-provided rating true, given the current scores
    return scores[rating[0]]<scores[rating[1]]
def metric():
    #number of true conditions
    return sum( map(evaluate_condition, ratings))

no_improvement_iterations=0 #number of successive iterations where there has been no improvement
current_score= metric()
while no_improvement_iterations<N_ITERATIONS:
    change_element= random.randint(0,N_ELEMS-1)
    new_value= random_score()
    old_value= scores[change_element]
    scores[change_element]= new_value
    new_score= metric()
    if new_score<=current_score:
        scores[change_element]= old_value
        no_improvement_iterations+=1
    else:
        no_improvement_iterations=0
        current_score= new_score

def distribute_scores(scores):
    '''distribute scores evently in the interval (MIN_SCORE, MAX_SCORE)'''
    sorted_scores= sorted(scores)
    order= [sorted_scores.index(x) for x in scores] #inefficient but easy to understand
    step= (MAX_SCORE-MIN_SCORE)/(len(order))
    return [x*step for x in order]

print "ratings:", ", ".join(["{0}<{1}".format(a,b) for a,b in ratings])
print "scores:", scores
print "distributed scores:", distribute_scores(scores)
```

And output:

```
ratings: 1<2, 3<4, 0<3, 4<3, 4<0
scores: [2.3647080073611955, 0.7188260611863462, 4.295792794993049, 4.286501742802684, 0.3471914376983337]
distributed scores: [2.0, 1.0, 4.0, 3.0, 0.0]
```

This is not strictly hill climbing, since we generate new_value randomly. Hill climbing would choose new_value to maximize the score, but we can't calculate that directly, so we use [random optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_optimization)

Also, obviously, this is not the best way to solve the search problem - a genetic algorithm that operated on the order would probably be faster, for example. I aimed for simplicity, not efficiency.